# Как правильно пользоваться параметром depth в json_decode, если хочу оставить вложенный массив в фомате JSON?

Tags: php, json

Есть двухуровневый массив закодированный в `json`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 28
    [2] => 185
    [3] => 70
    [4] => 3
    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => fgvbz
            [2] => xzcvzxcbxcb
            [3] => vcbcxbcvb
        )

    [6] => male
    [7] => true
)
```

как оставить в формате `json` вложенный массив? С параметром `depth` возникает ошибка, если указать меньше 3

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

> **depth** Указывает глубину рекурсии.

Этот параметр был введен для защиты от этак, связанных с переполнением памяти. У Вас объект содержит три уровня вложенности, поэтому параметр `depth` у Вас не может быть меньше трех. По умолчанию он имеет значение 512

Comment: Т.е. я должен отдельно обратно кодировать в `json` этот элемент?

Comment: @Leo240 зачем? Вы, что, не знаете какая у Вас может быть вложенность элементов?

Comment: просто мне нужно сохранить в `json`-формате для записи в ячейку таблицы sql этот вложенный массив, а элементы родительского массива раскидать по другим ячейкам

Comment: @Leo240 Вы не ответили на предыдущий вопрос. Вы знаете какой у Вас может быть уровень вложенности элементов?

Comment: да, только который уже есть

Comment: @Leo240 Ну так и укажите его